# ipynb file not opening in localhost internet explorer

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipynb

I am using a remote desktop for work. I can open jupyter notebook via the Anaconda Powershell but when I navigate to the .ipynb file and open it, it opens a new tab that just stays blank.

This was previously working on Google Chrome but for some reason Google Chrome was deleted from the remote desktop server I connect to and I don't have the access credentials to reinstall it.

Why wouldn't the .ipynb file open in Internet Explorer, and is there a way around this?

I have tried changing it from `/tree` to `/lab` to open a jupyter lab, but jupyter lab gives me [WinError 5] access is denied.